# Displaying a 4x4 board with headings '1,2,3,4' on the side and 'A,B,C,D' on the top

Tags: python

I'm trying to get my output to be

```
    A     B     C     D
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

But the current code adds the numbering before each vertical line. Would anyone have any suggestions?

```
board = [['    ', '    ', '    ', '    '],
         ['    ', '    ', '    ', '    '],
         ['    ', '    ', '    ', '    '],
         ['    ', '    ', '    ', '    ']]
max_row = len(board)
max_col = len(board[0])
def start_game():
i = 1
turn_number = 1
if choice == 1:
    print("Turn {}".format(turn_number))           #display 4x4 board
    print("    A     B     C     D   ")
    print(" +-----+-----+-----+-----+")
    for r in range(max_row):
        for c in range(max_col):
            #print("{}".format(i))
            print(i, end='')                 #something is wrong here
            print('|{}'.format(board[r][c]), end='')
        print(" |")
        print(" +-----+-----+-----+-----+")
    turn_number += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: just set a conditional to print `i` only if the `r` or `c` values are 1 or sth, it  could be the column variable but look for Yourself

Comment: Error: Choice is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop to a simple one -

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print("{}{}|".format(i,"|     "*4))
    print(" +-----+-----+-----+-----+")
```

Output:

```
    A     B     C     D   
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4|     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the printing of the statement:

```
def start_game():
    i = 1
    turn_number = 1
    choice=1
          #display 4x4 board
    print("Turn {}".format(turn_number))
    print("    A     B     C     D   ")
    print(" +-----+-----+-----+-----+")
    for r in range(max_row):
             
        for c in range(max_col):
            #===== Change here ========
            if choice==1:
                print(i, end='') 
                choice=2
            else:
                print(' ',end='')
            print('|{}'.format(board[r][c]), end='')
        print(" |")
        print(" +-----+-----+-----+-----+")
        #===== To update i, move it inside the loop
        turn_number += 1
        i += 1
        choice=1
start_game()
```