# Displaying characters within a 4x4 board

Tags: python

Now I found this link:
[Displaying a 4x4 board with headings '1,2,3,4' on the side and 'A,B,C,D' on the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427963/displaying-a-4x4-board-with-headings-1-2-3-4-on-the-side-and-a-b-c-d-on-the)

Which is exactly how I want my output as well. ie:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

My code:

```
import string
import random

random.seed(9999)
alphabet = []

print(" +-----+-----+-----+-----+")
for i in range(4):
    alphabet.append([])
    for g in range (1, 5):
        alphabet[i].append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))
output = [f"{n1} | {n2} | {n3} | {n4}" for n1, n2, n3, n4 in alphabet]
print(*output, sep="\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+\n")
```

Desired output(example):

```
Enter seed: 9999 
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
| L | | S | | Y | | U |
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
| P | | R | | A | | U |
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
| A | | K | | W | | V |
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
| L | | N | | A | | P |
+---+ +---+ +---+ +---+
```

How can I correct my f-strings to have my desired output?

Comment: _How can I correct my f-strings to have my desired output_ It would help if you showed us what the output is now, and explain how that's different from what you wanted.

Comment: Edited, I want to place my values within the 4x4 board so it "fits".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, You just need to manage your spacing.

```
random.seed(9999)
alphabet = []
x=' '
print("+-----+-----+-----+-----+")
for i in range(4):
    alphabet.append([])
    for g in range (1, 5):
        alphabet[i].append(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase))

output = [f"|{x*2}{n1}{x*2}|{x*2}{n2}{x*2}|{x*2}{n3}{x*2}|{x*2}{n4}{x*2}|" for n1, n2, n3, n4 in alphabet]
print(*output, sep="\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+\n+-----+-----+-----+-----+\n")
print("+-----+-----+-----+-----+")
```

For unique spacing you can use a variable like `x` and use in `f-string`

Result

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  D  |  F  |  Y  |  C  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  E  |  Z  |  G  |  J  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  G  |  V  |  Y  |  T  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  S  |  J  |  U  |  R  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I am getting whitespace between each row. I tried implementing strip function but it didn't work, any tips?

Comment: Are you getting whitespace with this code ?